# How this code (spaghetti of "setTimeout-s") can be rewritten?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me re-write this spaghetti of `setTimeout`s

*It's a animation: selected images highlights with a 1 sec interval*

```
var $pic_1 = $('.pic-1');
        var $pic_13 = $('.pic-13');
        var $pic_4 = $('.pic-4');
        var $pic_9 = $('.pic-9');
        var $pic_12 = $('.pic-12');
        var $pic_19 = $('.pic-19');
        var $pic_11 = $('.pic-11');
        var $pic_20 = $('.pic-20');

        function blinkImages() {
            $pic_1.css('opacity', 1);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $pic_1.css('opacity',.3);
                $pic_13.css('opacity', 1);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $pic_13.css('opacity',.3);
                    $pic_4.css('opacity', 1);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $pic_4.css('opacity',.3);
                        $pic_20.css('opacity', 1);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $pic_20.css('opacity',.3);
                            $pic_9.css('opacity', 1);
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                $pic_9.css('opacity',.3);
                                $pic_12.css('opacity', 1);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $pic_12.css('opacity',.3);
                                    $pic_19.css('opacity', 1);
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        $pic_19.css('opacity',.3);
                                        $pic_11.css('opacity',1);
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                            $pic_11.css('opacity',.3);
                                            blinkImages();
                                        },1000);
                                    },1000);
                                },1000);
                            },1000);
                        },1000);
                    },1000);
                },1000);
            }, 1000);
        }
        blinkImages();
```

Comment: you could create a recursive function or something like that.

Comment: sounds like a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you describe a bit what this code is actually doing? Is it a slideshow? (just a guess)

Comment: Just try to give `blinkImages()` a parameter and you'll see how the nesting trivially decreases…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
var seq=['.pic_1','.pic_13','.pic_4','.pic_20','.pic_9','.pic_12','.pic_19','.pic_11']
var cur = seq.shift();
$(cur).css('opacity', 1);
setInterval(function() {
    $(cur).css('opacity', 0.3);
    seq.push(cur);
    cur = seq.shift();
    $(cur).css('opacity', 1);
}, 1000);
```

There might be a glitch in the first loop, but you will probably be able to figure it out with that base code.

It seems to me that it should'nt be very far from what you have.